# How to preallocate arrays that grow with horzcat and vertcat

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab

Whenever an array grows inside a loop, we can easily preallocate it with `zeros` before the loop, as long as we know the number of iterations that are going to take place.

However, there are cases where we simply don't know the exact number of iterations, such as when we have a condition that must be previously met to grow the array.

For cases like this, since I don't know what size the output array will be, I do not know how to preallocate.

Take the following pseudocode as an example:

```
M = []; % Declare empty array.

for i = 1:n % This loop performs n iterations.
    if(condition == true)
        % Computations take place here
        % and yield an array --> v

        M = horzcat(M,v'); % Concatenate v as a new column of M.
    end
end
```

How would you preallocate `M` in this case?

Note that `horzcat(M,v')` is used to grow `M` column-wise for those iterations that satisfied the condition. So this same scenario would happen if we concatenated row-wise using `vertcat(M,v)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all rewrite your code to be compatible to preallocation. Use something like

```
M(k+1:k+numel(v))=v'
k=k+numel(v)
```

Use K to keep track of the space you really use. At the end cut of additional space allocated:

```
M=M(1:k)
```

Now you can experiment with different strategies, allocate the possible maximum(if known) , double size whenever array is full etc. Allocate the expected or most likely size. This depends on your problem.

Comment: I thought that preallocating an array was something that would take place one single time and strictly before loops, but as I understand now by reading your answer, it can also be accomplished inside loops on the go. This is though very confusing to me, since the `M` array still grows in size on every iteration!

Comment: Matlab allows you to allocate additional space "on the fly". Let's say you have `v` with 1000 elements, but you notice that you need at 2000. Writing `v(2000)=0` causes matlab to allocate the missing space in one step. Note that each extension of the array may require to move the full array to a new memory address, so you want to  avoid such steps, but you don't have to avoid them at all cost.

Comment: Understood. I guess it is mostly about intuition then. So that in most situations it would be just worth to preallocate an array of zeros before the loop, and make it big enough to make sure that enough space will be available, then after the loop, just shrink the array discarding the unused zeros...Heading back to the original problem of the question, now I see why using `horzcat` and `vertcat` makes no sense if I wish to fill preallocated arrays :)